# Installing ubuntu on dell inspiron

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install an Ubuntu on a Dell inspiron using a USB device, I went into BIOS and disabled Secure Boot, set the machine to boot from USB, the setup went well until I received the message that the installation is complete therefore I must restart the laptop. I restarted but when the machine comes up, I see Dell SupportAssist - "Boot failure on device", can anyone help?

Comment: Are you booting the right Hard Disk partition, the one where you installed Ubuntu? Maybe it is trying to boot some other partition. Is GRUB successfully installed? The issue could be many many things. including hardware failure on your Inspiron.

Comment: Did this computer come with Windows pre-installed? If so, which version? Did you replace Windows with Ubuntu during Ubuntu install? Is the BIOS set to UEFI or Legacy mode?

Comment: Did you switch the machine back from booting from USB?

Comment: Hi guys, to be exact - I have loaded the Ubuntu on the laptop hard drive, and when the machine was powering down it asked me to disconnect the media before  shutting down, I'm pretty sure that I have installed Ubuntu to the correct drive. The computer came with Windows pre-installed but I unfortunately smacked the OS

Comment: And when I switch UEFI on and off, boot the machine and select booting booting form a hard drive with USB plugged in, the machine boots fine, but without USB| It says Boot failure on device. BIOS is set to Secure Boot Disabled

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: @luclanpowr Please [edit] the question to add details.

Comment: From what you've said so far, it sounds like you accidentally installed GRUB (the bootloader) on the USB drive. That or your BIOS settings are messed up.

Comment: Okay guys, let me drop some more details - I think I'm probably getting somewhere, now, if I go into BIOS and enable Secure Boot and restart the machine, a hard drive does not appear, then I reboot and change Secure Boot to Disable, save and reset, then hard drive appears and I'm able to select it. After that - Ubuntu boots up fine and can see the desktop and able to open a terminal and everything and can use the machine. But problem is, if I reboot then it goes back to Boot failure on device, can I do anything after it boot into Ubuntu, before shutting down or restarting?